# How should I create and read a user editable configuration file in ~/.config or similar?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I am planning a command line Python application that I intend to distribute through PyPi.

When the application is installed with pip, I want to create a user-editable configuration file in the appropriate location on the user's filesystem.

For example, in Ubuntu, the file would be something like ~/.config/foo/config.ini

On installation I want to create the file (if possible) and be able to specify another config file to use instead with a command line parameter.

What is the usual scheme for getting this done?

Comment: The program can create the file when it is run for the first time.

Comment: Just don't forget to create the directory. You cannot create a file if the directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think `appdirs` package on PyPI is what you need, isn’t it?

Comment: Nowadays [_`platformdirs`_](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) seems to be a better, more reliable choice.

Answer (score 0):

A project such as [`platformdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) can help with such a task. It implements [*Freedesktop*'s "XDG Base Directory Specification"](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Don't create the file at installation time though. It is preferable to create the file when it is actually needed, this might be during the first run of the application for example.

Something like the following should get you started with the configuration directory:

```
>>> import platformdirs
>>> platformdirs.user_config_dir('foo')
'/home/sinoroc/.config/foo'
```

Or without external dependency, it could roughly look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import os
import pathlib
import platform

def get_config_file_path(project_name, file_name):
    path = None
    config_path = None
    platform_system = platform.system()
    if platform_system == 'Windows':
        if 'APPDATA' in os.environ:
            config_path = pathlib.Path(os.environ['APPDATA'])
        else:
            config_path = pathlib.Path.home().joinpath('AppData', 'Roaming')
    elif platform_system == 'Linux':
        if 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME' in os.environ:
            config_path = pathlib.Path(os.environ['XDG_CONFIG_HOME'])
        else:
            config_path = pathlib.Path.home().joinpath('.config')
    if config_path:
        path = config_path.joinpath(project_name, file_name)
    return path

def main():
    default_config_file_path = get_config_file_path('foo', 'config.ini')
    args_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args_parser.add_argument(
        '--config', '-c',
        default=str(default_config_file_path),
        type=argparse.FileType('r'),
    )
    args = args_parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) module for this as it reliably handles differences across different platforms:

```
>>> from appdirs import user_config_dir
>>> appname = "SuperApp"
>>> appauthor = "Acme"
>>> user_config_dir(appname)
'/home/trentm/.config/SuperApp'
```

Comment: Nowadays [_`platformdirs`_](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) seems to be a better, more reliable choice.