# Does pip offer any way for particular files within a package to be unaffected by new versions of the package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-packaging

I have never worked with pip before and I am trying to figure out if there is any way to have a ***particular file in a pip package*** I created never be overwritten when introduced to new package versions.

To better explain, let's say I have a json file, `data.json`, within the package itself. Let's also say that the contents of this json file can be updated by someone using this package. A new version of the package just came out, and this user decides to install it with the expectation that ***the information within the json file to not have been impacted by the update***.

***Question:*** In this context, does pip offer any tools that would have data.json be not overwritten by new versions of the package?

I have been looking at the pip documentation for quite some time and it is a bit overwhelming. I have encountered metadata for the `setup.py` script such as `packaging_data` that allows files such as this json file to be included within the package; but to what I understand it does not accomplish what I need.

I have also pondered making it the responsibility of the user to provide a file path for data.json to be saved and read/written from, but I then run into the same issue: ***how can the package remember the file path they provided?***

I believe it maybe good to note that ***this package is built exclusively with Python 3***. I may have not been able to explain this the best so if you are confused please let me know.

Comment: You should look at those: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64459990/11138259 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158936/11138259 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59354676/11138259

Comment: @sinoroc Will do, thanks for the info